# ! Font MY1/mtt/b/it/10.3=mtmib at 10.3pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. <to be read again>

Tags: pdftex

I want to compile the template [SIMDOC.TEX](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291097-0258/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm). I get the following error

```
! Font MY1/mtt/b/it/10.3=mtmib at 10.3pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. <to be read again>
```

I believe the following code

```
\usepackage[T1,mtbold]{mathtime}
```

produces this error (if I remove it, this error disappears). I have downloaded mathtime-ltx from CTAN, ran the command `latex mathtime.ins` and I moved all the files into the directory which contains the original file that is producing errors when compiling it.
I've seen some posts that the `texlive-recommended` should be installed. I've checked and I have them installed. I am Using Ubuntu and Texmaker.
What should I do to overcome this problem?

Comment: `mathtime` requires proprietary fonts. Remove that line; the people you'll submit the paper to will add it back.

Comment: @egreg: In miktex I can compile the template (if  the packages `mathtime` +  `belleek`  are installed) without using proprietary fonts.

Comment: You could try to use the miktex packages: get mathtime and belleek from `http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages`. Unpack them and move the files where they belong in your local texmf, then add `\pdfmapfile{=belleek.map}` to your document and hope ...